# What's is the use of <security-constraint> in web.xml in Google app engine GWT Java

Tags: java, xml, google-app-engine, ssl, gwt

I am working on projects using GWT java on google app engine. I want to access my app with https so I can access my app using "myapp-dot-appspot.com". However, I want to know whats is the use of:

```
<security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>profile</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/profile/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```

configuration in web.xml.

Answer (score 0):

It means that:

> Requests using HTTP (non-secure) for URLs whose transport guarantee is CONFIDENTIAL are automatically redirected to the same URL using HTTPS.

So all requests to http://myapp.appspot.com/profile/%anything% will be redirected to https://myapp.appspot.com/profile/%anything%

See docs: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml#Secure_URLs